# Extjs Combobox store not filtering values on typeahead

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm having trouble in filtering the comboxbox on typeahead, when I type the required value which I want, the combo highlights the value correctly but it does not filters the store. The store reloads to the original data even after typing some text in the combobox.

Here is my code for store.

```
    Ext.define('Dashboard.store.Rule', {
         extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
         model: 'Dashboard.model.Rule',
         storeId : 'Rule',
         pageSize: 35,
         autoSync : false,
         autoLoad: true,
         remoteFilter: true,
         sorters : ['ruleName'],
         proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           api: {
                    read : 'rule/view.action',
                    create : 'rule/create.action',
                    update: 'rule/update.action',
                    destroy: ''
           },
           reader: {                    //reads the data in the JSON Format
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data',
                    successProperty: 'success'
           },
           writer: {
                      type: 'json',         //writes the data in the JSON Format
                      writeAllFields: true,
                      encode: true,
                      root: 'data'
           },
           listeners: {             //Exception Handler for the Ajax Request
                      exception: function(proxy, response, operation){

                      var error = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                      Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                  title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                                  msg: error.message,
                                  icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                   buttons: Ext.Msg.OK

                      });
                   }
              } 
         }
    });
```

And below is my code for combobox in view

```
    xtype: 'combobox',
    id : 'ruleName',
    padding : '10 30 10 20',
    fieldLabel: '<html><font color = "red">*</font></html>Rule Name',
    store: 'Rule',    
    width: screen.width*0.22,
    emptyText: 'Select Rule',
    typeAhead : true,
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    lastQuery:'',
    displayField: 'ruleName',
    disabled : true,
    maxLength: 100,
    maxLengthText: 'Maximum text size allowed 100',
    listeners : {
           'change' : function(){
                          //TODO
           },
           'blur' : function(){
                        //TODO
           }

     }
```

I also tried putting `triggerAction : 'all'` but still nothing works.

Please help on this issue

Many Thanks

Comment: Since you have activated remoteFilter, your filter should be on the server. I would guess that you didn't implement any filter on the server, right?

Comment: Yes Alexander I am not implementing remoteFilter, But onload I am bring all the data from server. But I can't understand why it is firing ajax request with every character I type. Do I am missing some config property which is mandatory for this situation. Kindly help..

Comment: You told him **explicitly** to use this kind of behaviour by stating `remoteFilter:true`.

Comment: I tried by setting it false but still it doesn't work, does it has to do something with queryParam since i am setting queryMode: 'remote' and in the docs it is mentioned "Name of the parameter used by the Store to pass the typed string when the ComboBox is configured with queryMode: 'remote'." for query param

Comment: @ManishSharma - Did your solution work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your store is configured with

```
remoteFilter: true,
```

which tells the store to reload whenever the filter is changed, sending the filter configuration to the server, so a server-side filter can be applied.

The records that are sent back by the server are not filtered by the client, since the server should have done that.

Did you implement a filter server-side? If so, what's your filter code there?

If you didn't mean to filter server-side, set remoteFilter to false.